# Cartesian Product without Itertools A Non Pythonic approach

Tags: python, cartesian-product

I have this code here:

```
import itertools

col_groups = [c1+c2 for c1, c2 in itertools.product(d1_columns, d2_columns)]
```

How can I do something like this without itertools? a non-pythonic way of doing it.

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: @PeterDeGlopper just curiosity.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps with a nested list comprehension if you just need the cartesian product of two lists.

```
[ i + j for i in d1_columns for j in d2_columns ]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def colGroups(d1, d2):
  answer = []
  for c1 in d1:
    for c2 in d2:
      answer.append(c1+c2)
  return answer
```

Testing:

```
>>> d1 = list(range(10))
>>> d2 = list(range(10,20))
>>> d1
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>> d2
[10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]
>>> def colGroups(d1, d2):
...   answer = []
...   for c1 in d1:
...     for c2 in d2:
...       answer.append(c1+c2)
...   return answer
... 
>>> colGroups(d1, d2)
[10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28]
```

... or the nested listcomp equivalent:

```
colGroups = [c1+c2 for c1 in d1 for c2 in d2]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can always use the code given in [itertools.product](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product)

```
def product(*args, **kwds):
    # product('ABCD', 'xy') --> Ax Ay Bx By Cx Cy Dx Dy
    # product(range(2), repeat=3) --> 000 001 010 011 100 101 110 111
    pools = map(tuple, args) * kwds.get('repeat', 1)
    result = [[]]
    for pool in pools:
        result = [x+[y] for x in result for y in pool]
    for prod in result:
        yield tuple(prod)
```

Comment: humm thats in interesting way of avoiding to use itertools.

Comment: I am getting this error tho:

unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'map' and 'int'

Comment: What are the parameters you are passing?

Comment: I have it something like this: I created above function... then I do a function call and pass the function like this inside another function: col_groups = [c1+c2 for c1, c2 in product(d1_columns, d2_columns)]

Comment: Can you please show me what are `dl_columns` and `d2_columns`?

Comment: d1_columns = zip(*d1.values())
d2_columns = zip(*d2.values())

d1 and d2 are two dictionary tables

Comment: @user3029969 Can you please edit your question with your latest program?